# Modify success message when the form is delivered

Tags: javascript, php, forms, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I really want to have a better aspect in the "deivered" page of my form. Is it possible to use "SWEETALERT2"??

This is my form code in html:

```
<form class="form-2" id="contact-emotion" method="POST" action="telefono.php">
    <label id="nombre1" for="nombre">Nombre:</label> 
    <input type="text" id="nick" name="nombre1" placeholder="Tu nombre.." required>
    <label id="tel" for="telefono"></label>
    <input type="tel" id="te-llamamos" name="telefono1" placeholder="Déjanos tu teléfono y te llamamos..." onkeypress="return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57" pattern="(6|7|8|9)[ -]*([0-9][ -]*){8}" required>
    <input type="submit" class="btn-llamanos" value="ok"  id="submit-1" name="enviar1">
</form>
```

and this is the telefono.php response:

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar1'])) {
    $destino="xime.marquez@gmail.com";
    $nombre1 = filter_var($_POST['nombre1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $llamame = filter_var($_POST['telefono1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $fecha_registro = date("Y-m-d");
    $contenido = "Fecha: " . $fecha_registro . "\nNombre: "  . $nombre1 . "\nTelefono-contacto: " . $llamame;

    $mail = mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido);
    $alerta = "¡GENIAL! ¡Muchas gracias por contactarnos! En breve te llamaremos y aclararemos tus dudas";
    echo 
    "<script>if(confirm('$alerta'));
    window.location = 'https://www.emotion360.es/EmotionWeb/';  
    </script>";

} else {
    echo "<script>alert('No pudimos procesar tu información. Por favor, intenta de nuevo')</script>"; 
}
```

How could I change to sweetalert? Is it possible? Please I dont want this cold message!!!

[image: This is my alert now]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

For Sweetalert2 use its library [click here to check library](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples)

You need first to add this library file before calling sweetalert code

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

then do this code

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar1'])) {

    $destino="xime.marquez@gmail.com";
    $nombre1 = filter_var($_POST['nombre1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $llamame = filter_var($_POST['telefono1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $fecha_registro = date("Y-m-d");
    $contenido = "Fecha: " . $fecha_registro . "\nNombre: "  . $nombre1 . "\nTelefono-contacto: " . $llamame;

    $mail = mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido);

    $alerta = "¡GENIAL! ¡Muchas gracias por contactarnos! En breve te llamaremos y aclararemos tus dudas";
    echo 
    "<script>
        Swal.fire({
            title: '',
            text: '".$alerta."',
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                window.location = 'https://www.emotion360.es/EmotionWeb/';  
            }
        })
      </script>";

} else {
    echo "<script>Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: '',text: 'No pudimos procesar tu información. Por favor, intenta de nuevo'})</script>"; 
}
```

Comment: My comments in the other answer... sorry to insist!

Comment: The answer is same as I told call the library file before the script of `Swal.fire()`, where is `Swal.fire` in the answer?

Comment: No problem Siddhart, I will keep triying, for sure with your information I could solve it!! Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

For the installation I just have to add:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

in telephono.php before open de php tag???

And thats it?

I think my issue is there because the form works correctly without the sweetalert.

Then I change it exactly from yours like:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>    

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['enviar1'])) {

    $destino="xime.marquez@gmail.com";
    $nombre1 = filter_var($_POST['nombre1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $llamame = filter_var($_POST['telefono1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $fecha_registro = date("Y-m-d");
    $contenido = "Fecha: " . $fecha_registro . "\nNombre: "  . $nombre1 . "\nTelefono-contacto: " . $llamame;

    $mail = mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido);

...
```

And is giving me the blank "telefono.php" page without the alert!! =(